# SQL : Select a parent record if all values in a child table are FALSE

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm having this problem with my query : I'm trying to get all the records from the parent table when ALL the values of the children table are either nonexistant or FALSE.

The tables look like this :

```
Admission (parent table)            Courses (child table)
------------------------            ---------------------
IDAdmission                         IDCourse
[Other data]                        IDAdmission 
                                    CourseCompleted
                                    [Other data]
```

Where one admission can have multiple (or none) courses.

For instance, if my query was

```
SELECT Admission.IDAdmission, Courses.IDCourse, Courses.IDAdmission,
Courses.CourseCompleted FROM Admission LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses ON 
Admission.IDAdmission = Courses.IDAdmission
```

I would obtain the following records :

```
Admission           Courses
IDAdmission         IDCourse    IDAdmission    CourseCompleted
--------------------------------------------------------------
123                 001         123            false
123                 002         123            true
456                 001         456            false
456                 004         456            false
456                 006         456            false
789                 002         789            true
789                 006         789            false
345                 NULL        NULL           NULL
```

Now, what I'm looking for is to get the records from the parent table `Admission` ONLY if all the `CourseCompleted` criteria is false. If the criteria is `NULL`, it should also be selected.

Therefore, from the above data, I'd like to select the following from the parent table `Admission` :

```
IDAdmission
-----------
456
345
```

I'm trying to get this information out in a report, therefore I cannot use temporary tables. I've looked into Anti-Join, but I'm not sure it would solve my issue (or perhaps, I misunderstood their usefulness in this situation).

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The answers already posted will work but just FYI: There is no reason to think that you cannot use temp tables for a report. Almost every complex report I write I used temp tables. The dataset query does not have to be a single statement as long as the only output SELECT statement is the one you want. Basically if you can run it in SSMS and it only gives a single result set back then you can use the exact same code in an SSRS dataset query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub-query within `EXISTS` to exclude all the admission recrods with at least 1 completed course.

```
SELECT
    Admission.IDAdmission
FROM Admission
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Courses C2
    WHERE C2.IDAdmission = Admission.IDAdmission
        AND C2.CourseCompleted = 'true'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select a.IDAdmission 
from Admission a 
where not exists (select 1 from Courses c 
                  where c.IDAdmission =  a.IDAdmission 
                  and c.CourseCompleted = true)
```